# Did Jaskier have any romantic interest in Geralt?

Tags: the-witcher

The bard Jaskier traveled with Geralt for some time, as shown in the first season. In the second season, he seems fairly distraught about Geralt having abandoned him, seeming to tear up a little at one point and even having written a biting song ("Burn Butcher Burn") about the end of their journey together, with lyrics like "after everything we did, we saw, you turned your back on me" that would not be out of place in a breakup song. In fact, he seems to have taken the end of his travels with Geralt much harder than Yennefer, who actually *had* a romantic relationship with Geralt.

Of course, Jaskier is easily slighted and prone to be overdramatic in every aspect of his life, so perhaps that is all that is going on. Still, the "jilted lover" feel seems to be there. Is there any indication in the show, books, or interviews that Jaskier has or had an unrequited attraction to Geralt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they’re just bffs and love each other but in a none romantic way. Lauren, the show runner, has addressed this in the past:

> When we asked Hissrich about Jaskier's relationship with Geralt, the showrunner denied any deliberate homoerotic undertones, stating instead that it's "just an example of male friendship".
>
> "These are men who… one of them is very passionate, and very creative, and is able to express his feelings; and one is not at all... But they both ultimately love each other very much."
>
> <sub>[Digital Spy, Is The Witcher gay, or very gay?](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a30316466/the-witcher-netflix-gay-lgbtq-representation-jaskier/)</sub>

I will also note that just because Jaskier is creative and in touch with his emotions as well as caring about Geralt doesn’t mean that he has to be gay.

Comment: Of course, that Jaskier cares about Geralt and is open about it does not mean that he has to be romantically interested in him, which is why I did not ask this question after the first season. But when he took Geralt's departure very hard, to the point of writing a song about the end of their relationship, that made me start thinking that Jaskier might have had feelings toward Geralt.

Comment: His deep hurt could also be partly because a major source of his income (the constant influx of new material for his songs) is cut off...

Comment: @Adamant they’re best friends and Jaskier expresses a lot of emotion through songs (as well as making his money there). It makes sense that he would write a song about it.

Comment: According to Season 3, Jaskier absolutely has shown romantic and sexual interest in men, but completely denies any interest in Geralt.

Comment: @Adamant apparently so, I think this is another way the show is slightly butchering the source material.

Answer (score 1):

If going by canon, neither Jaskier/Geralt nor Yennefer/Geralt had any form of break-up drama after the Villentretenmerth (Three Jackdaws/golden dragon) adventure.

Geralt and Yennefer break up and get together again at multiple times through the books. In this short-story they actually get together again. The quote from Villentretenmerth addressing Yennefer, which does *not* come after any form of drama, is (*Sword of Destiny, VIII*):

> You were made for each other, you and the Witcher. But nothing will come of it. Nothing. I'm sorry.

My take on this quote is not that he refers to them getting together romantically, but that he refers to Yennefer and Geralt never getting a (biological) child together, since Yennefer's whole reason for taking part in the dragon hunt was to find a cure that would turn a sorceress fertile. Especially since (big spoiler):

> Yennefer and Geralt do get together romantically after Ciri brings them together, just before the Thanedd Coup. From there on they never break up (although Geralt has a fling with Fringilla while staying in Toussaint) and supposedly marry in the end, though Sapkowski's short-story about their wedding is as I understand it not regarded as canon even by the author himself.

Earlier in the same short-story, Geralt, Three Jackdaws, Téa and Véa are all sharing a bath tub naked "off-screen". Some might take that as Geralt being at least bi-curious. But this happened before Jaskier enters that story.

There is no indication of Jaskier being bisexual anywhere in the books (unlike for example Ciri and Triss). However, he probably has more brief heterosexual relations than all of the other characters combined :)

Comment: The show may be a seperate canon to the books but that doesn't mean the show isn't canon - it's canon to itself. You might want to specify what you mean here. Lastly, most of this answer focuses on things outside of Jaskier and the little bits that do are throwaway lines. As with your other recent answer I'm not seeing how a lot of this is relevant.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The OP is asking for references from the books, which as it would seem everyone but you regard as Witcher fan canon. The reason why Jaskier is annoyed in the show goes back to the Villentretenmerth episode, why a comparison of that episode versus the short-story in the books is highly relevant. The show ends with Geralt breaking up with Yennefer and Jaskier both, the story in the books contains nothing of that drama. Also the quote by the character Villentretenmerth leading up to to the drama is different in the show and the books.

Comment: I think perhaps you've misunderstood me in my previous comments so I'll disengage from that discussion. What I mean is that the comparison is tangential information at best to the question at hand which is does Jaskier have a romantic interest in Geralt. The only parts of this answer that really focus on that, that I can see, is the last paragraph. I'm aware it's hard to prove a negative but it might be prudent to focus more on expanding that point, the main one in relation to the question, than the tangential information that the answer instead focuses on.

Comment: Re Villentretenmerth's quote - see [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3202/17) on another SE site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I doubt that is a correct answer then, as per the above spoiler. The part quoted in that answer happens early on before Blood of Elves and Ciri's story kicks off.

Comment: > they never break up or have other partners

Fringilla Vigo disagrees

Comment: @Bartors Oh right, I forgot about that. Although Geralt used that relation to send the Lodge on a wild goose chase, so he definitely did have ulterior motives.